# Can I install wood stair treads over old Linoleum

Tags: wood, stairs, linoleum

Installing maple tread and riser kits into my bi-level home. The stairs currently have linoleum on them. The lino peals up easy leaving a the paper glue layer on the stairs. Can I install the solid wood treads over the paper glue left behind without issues? Using adhesive and maybe some small brad nails?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is no big deal.  Given that you might want to glue them anyway to reduce squeaking.  If you have big glue pieces hit it with a putty knife but don't need to spend a ton of time on it.